# Is there a way I can configure Netlify Forms in my React App to send both me and the user an email?

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I am looking to configure Netlify forms, or at least have a front end solution only that acts similar to Contact Form 7 in WordPress where when a form is submitted it will go to both me and the person who submitted it.

Is this possible in Netlify and if not, which solutions do you recommend. (Front End/Client Side only please)

Answer (score 0):

Not currently.

You could instead create a Netlify/AWS/Azure serverless function to handle your form submissions and route emails via Sendgrid. You would be able to send any emails you wanted in response to a form submission then.

Comment: I see, Seems to be a pretty big limitation/headache that requires a lot of set up and services for something so simple.